# Removing carriage returns using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following SQL which concatenates my address fields into `ADDRESSLINE1`:

```
SELECT Isnull(ADDRESSLINE1 + Char(13)+Char(10), '')
       + Isnull(ADDRESSLINE2 + Char(13)+Char(10), '')
       + Isnull(ADDRESSLINE3, '') AS ADDRESSLINE1
```

It returns:

```
ADDRESSLINE1       
------------------ -----------------------------------
10 TEST ROAD



(1 row(s) affected)
```

How do I amend my code so that if `ADDRESSLINE2` AND `ADDRESSLINE3` are blank '' then remove the unnecessary carriage returns.

I would expect:

```
ADDRESSLINE1       
------------------ -----------------------------------
10 TEST ROAD

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: case when ADDRESSLINE1 is not null then ,,, else '' end etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the CR+LF to each line, then use the `REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE()))` method to remove the last 2 characters.

```
SELECT REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(Isnull(ADDRESSLINE1 + Char(13)+Char(10), '')
       + Isnull(ADDRESSLINE2 + Char(13)+Char(10), '')
       + Isnull(ADDRESSLINE3 + Char(13)+Char(10), '')),1,2,'')) AS ADDRESSLINE1
```

Try this if you've got empty strings in your fields:

```
SELECT REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(Isnull(NULLIF(ADDRESSLINE1,'') + Char(13)+Char(10), '')
       + Isnull(NULLIF(ADDRESSLINE2,'') + Char(13)+Char(10), '')
       + Isnull(NULLIF(ADDRESSLINE3,'') + Char(13)+Char(10), '')),1,2,'')) AS ADDRESSLINE1
```

Comment: @PriceCheaperton Works fine for me.  If you're in SSMS, make sure you've got it set to "Results to text".  Results to grid will strip line breaks.

Comment: @PriceCheaperton Do your fields *already* contain CR+LF or a CR?  Does `LEN(ADDERSSLINE1)` or whatever return the expected results, or is it off by 1 or 2?

Comment: @PriceCheaperton Then I have no idea.  This works perfectly fine for me no matter how I change strings to nulls: `SELECT REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(Isnull('Line 1' + Char(13)+Char(10), '') + Isnull('Line 2' + Char(13)+Char(10), '') + Isnull(null + Char(13)+Char(10), '')),1,2,''))`.

Comment: @PriceCheaperton Wait, are you sure there are no empty strings in your database?  You're sure they're actually nulls?  What happens if you specify `NULLIF(ADDRESSLINE1,'')` instead of `ADDRESSLINE1`,  `NULLIF(ADDRESSLINE2,'')` instead of `ADDRESSLINE2`, and so forth for each field?

Comment: There are empty strings in my database. That is the dilema. Sorry to have confused.